# cut date vector with self-defined breaks

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I would like to cut the date range according to the defined `breaks` (0-7 days, 8-15 days, ..., 31-50 days), then calculate the group average of the values.

```
library(dplyr)

date = seq(as.Date("2019/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 50)
value = matrix(rnorm(200, 100, 50), nrow=50) %>% data.frame()
sample = cbind(date, value) %>% data.frame()

breaks = c(0, 7, 15, 30, 50)

sample %>%
  group_by(cutt = cut(StayDate, breaks=breaks)) %>%
  summarise(m1 = mean(X1), m2=mean(X2))
```

However, it seems that `cut` function can only use "day", "week", etc. to cut. Is there any way I can make it?

Comment: I assume `StayDate` should refer to column `date` in `sample`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may convert to `"factor"` and back to `"numeric"`.

```
library(dplyr)
sample %>%
  group_by(cutt=cut(as.numeric(factor(date)), breaks=breaks)) %>%
  summarise(m1=mean(X1), m2=mean(X2))
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# cutt       m1    m2
# <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 (0,7]   126.  120. 
# 2 (7,15]  123.   90.3
# 3 (15,30]  82.6 107. 
# 4 (30,50]  90.4 104.
```

Or in base R:

```
do.call(rbind, by(sample[2:3], cut(as.numeric(factor(sample$date)), breaks), colMeans))
#                X1        X2
# (0,7]   125.79941 120.01652
# (7,15]  122.82247  90.33681
# (15,30]  82.64698 107.13250
# (30,50]  90.39701 104.09779
```

#### Data

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 50
sample <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2019/1/1"), by="day", length.out=n),
                  matrix(rnorm(4*n, 100, 50), ncol=4, 
                         dimnames=list(NULL, paste0("X", 1:4))))
breaks <- c(0, 7, 15, 30, 50)
```

Comment: Using `aggregate` is probably more efficient in base R - e.g. `aggregate(cbind(X1,X2) ~ cbind(date=cut(date, min(date) + breaks)), data=sample, FUN=mean)`

Comment: @thelatemail You're right! _Ronak Shah_'s dplyr solution seems to be even faster, though.

Comment: @jay.sf - absolutely. I suspect `aggregate` is not very fast generally and would be beaten by dplyr most of the time. It should be signficantly quicker than `by`/`rbind` though.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to divide the `date` based on number of days, you could subtract each `date` with the `first` `date`. Using @jay.sf's data

```
library(dplyr)

sample %>%
  mutate(new_date = as.integer(date - first(date)) + 1L) %>%
  group_by(cutt = cut(new_date, breaks = breaks)) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(X1, X2), mean)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  cutt     X1    X2
#  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1 (0,7]   126.  120. 
#2 (7,15]  123.   90.3
#3 (15,30]  82.6 107. 
#4 (30,50]  90.4 104.
```

In your example, you have consecutive `date` but in case if there is difference between dates this code would take that into consideration but I am not sure if that is intended.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,lapply(.SD, mean) , .(cutt = cut(as.numeric(factor(date)), 
           breaks = breaks)), .SDcols = X1:X2]
#     cutt        X1        X2
#1:   (0,7] 125.79941 120.01652
#2:  (7,15] 122.82247  90.33681
#3: (15,30]  82.64698 107.13250
#4: (30,50]  90.39701 104.09779
```

Comment: Do you know a base R answer hat's faster than the dplyr code?

Comment: @jay.sf  yes, i know

Comment: `colMeans` should be more efficient than `mean` but I only could figure it out with a `by`split which slows it down